# How to find the index of a tuple in a 2D array in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array with the form as follows (with much more elements):

```
coords = np.array(
    [[(2, 1), 1613, 655],
     [(2, 5), 906, 245],
     [(5, 2), 0, 0]])
```

And I would like to find the index of a specific tuple. For example, I might be looking for the position of the tuple `(2, 5)`, which should be in position `1` in this case.

I have tried with `np.where` and `np.argwhere`, with no luck:

```
pos = np.argwhere(coords == (2,5))
print(pos)
>> DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.

pos = np.where(coords == (2,5))
print(pos)
>> DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
```

How can I get the index of a tuple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you intend to use a numpy array containing objects, all comparison will be done using python itself. At that point, you have given up almost all the advantages of numpy and may as well use a list:

```
coords = coords.tolist()
index = next((i for i, n in enumerate(coords) if n[0] == (2, 5)), -1)
```

If you really want to use numpy, I suggest you transform your data appropriately. Two simple options come to mind. You can either expand your tuple and create an array of shape `(N, 4)`, or you can create a structured array that preserves the arrangement of the data as a unit, and has shape `(N,)`. The former is much simpler, while the later is, in my opinion, more elegant.

If you flatten the coordinates:

```
coords = np.array([[x[0][0], x[0][1], x[1], x[2]] for x in coords])
index = np.flatnonzero(np.all(coords[:, :2] == [2, 5], axis=1))
```

The structured solution:

```
coordt = np.dtype([('x', np.int_), ('y', np.int_)])
dt = np.dtype([('coord', coordt), ('a', np.int_), ('b', np.int_)])

coords = np.array([((2, 1), 1613, 655), ((2, 5), 906, 245), ((5, 2), 0, 0)], dtype=dt)

index = np.flatnonzero(coords['coord'] == np.array((2, 5), dtype=coordt))
```

You can also just transform the first part of your data to a real numpy array, and operate on that:

```
coords = np.array(coords[:, 0].tolist())
index = np.flatnonzero((coords == [2, 5]).all(axis=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not compare (2, 5) and coords, but compare (2, 5) and coords[:, 0].

Try this code.

```
np.where([np.array_equal(coords[:, 0][i], (2, 5)) for i in range(len(coords))])[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
import numpy as np
coords = np.array([[(2, 1), 1613, 655], [(2, 5), 906, 245], [(5, 2), 0, 0]])
tpl=(2,5)
i=0 # index of the column in which the tuple you are looking for is listed

pos=([t[i] for t in coords].index(tpl))
print(pos)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your target tuple (e.g. `(2,5)` ) is always in the first column of the numpy array `coords` i.e. `coords[:,0]` you can simply do the following without any loops!

```
[*coords[:,0]].index((2,5))
```

If the tuples aren't necessarily in the first column always, then you can use,

```
[*coords.flatten()].index((2,5))//3
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, the tuple `(2, 5)` is in position 0 as it is the first element of the list `[(2, 5), 906, 245]`.
And second of all, you can use basic python functions to check the index of a tuple in that array. Here's how you do it:

```py
>>> coords = np.array([[(2, 1), 1613, 655], [(2, 5), 906, 245], [(5, 2), 0, 0]])
>>> 
>>> coords_list = cl = list(coords)
>>> cl
[[(2, 1), 1613, 655], [(2, 5), 906, 245], [(5, 2), 0, 0]]
>>> 
>>> tuple_to_be_checked = tuple_ = (2, 5)
>>> tuple_
(2, 5)
>>> 
>>> for i in range(0, len(cl), 1):  # Dynamically works for any array `cl`
        for j in range(0, len(cl[i]), 1):  # Dynamic; works for any list `cl[i]`
            if cl[i][j] == tuple_:  # Found the tuple
                # Print tuple index and containing list index
                print(f'Tuple at index {j} of list at index {i}')
                break  # Break to avoid unwanted loops

Tuple at index 0 of list at index 1
>>>
```